# re-arrange column order in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the below dataframe:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("META",from=start,to=end)
class(META)
META<-data.frame(META)
class(META) # convert from xts to df
META
META$date<-as.Date(row.names(META))
head(META)

> head(META)
           META.Open META.High META.Low META.Close META.Volume
2013-01-02     27.44     28.18    27.42      28.00    69846400
2013-01-03     27.88     28.47    27.59      27.77    63140600
2013-01-04     28.01     28.93    27.83      28.76    72715400
2013-01-07     28.69     29.79    28.65      29.42    83781800
2013-01-08     29.51     29.60    28.86      29.06    45871300
2013-01-09     29.67     30.60    29.49      30.59   104787700
           META.Adjusted       date
2013-01-02         28.00 2013-01-02
2013-01-03         27.77 2013-01-03
2013-01-04         28.76 2013-01-04
2013-01-07         29.42 2013-01-07
2013-01-08         29.06 2013-01-08
2013-01-09         30.59 2013-01-09
```

And I would like to re-arrange the column order, say for date column, I would like to re-arrange from the sixth column to first, may I know how should I do it? Thank you so much.

Comment: `META[, c("date", setdiff(names(META), "date"))]` is one method

Comment: or `dplyr::relocate(META, "date")`